# How to create this layout in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, material-design, material-ui

[image]

My question in details
1- I want to make the toolbar shaped like half circle with lighting color in front of it
2- create something like a circle surrounded by 6 small parts of a circle which has an arrow refers to each category when it is clicked.
3-each category should has a suitable size of clickable area.

Any hints or tutorials may help me to implement this layout?

Comment: What are the expected interactions here? I understand all the categories are clickable. What about the circle in the middle? Can you do something with it, or is it just a static image?

Comment: @MarcinJedynak the small arrow has dynamic moving when such category is clicked, it points to it.

Comment: I think you're looking at a custom view and drawing it by hand here with custom hit tracking.  Its much too non-rectangular for a layout file to work well.

Comment: For the circle thing surrounded by the  6 other things, it looks like you could use a GridLayout (4 rows, 3 columns) with the circle thing spanning rows 1 & 2.

Comment: try to find FAB with cicrular actions. There are lot of libraries. You can then specify the background to look like this and have a listener for each of the actions. Try some of those [https://github.com/ogaclejapan/ArcLayout](https://github.com/ogaclejapan/ArcLayout) or this [http://www.viralandroid.com/2016/03/android-arc-menu-tutorial-with-example.html](http://www.viralandroid.com/2016/03/android-arc-menu-tutorial-with-example.html) or this [https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/2936](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/2936)

Comment: You can design your custom Widget class using Android Canvas and ondraw() function. please see answer bellow to get more idea.

Comment: That's not material design, by the way

Comment: yes i also agree with @cricket_007, This kind of layout always cause performance issue and time consuming for developer.

Answer (score 4):

It is custom layout designed by your designer and Android standard layout may not fit your requirement.There will be many options to proceed with. You need to select approach which mach best to your requirement and create responsive User Interface(Fitting properly on most of the android devices)

**Option 1 :**

Entirely design your layout take different Menu images from designer. Create your custom widget class. Draw Center Circle as per selected value. refresh layout every time user clicks any menu Item. Here you need write your own logic to capture different `onClick` and `onTouch` events.
This option reacquires lot of logic,but you will get more accuracy. I prefer this option many times. You can go through links bellow to understand creating custom widget in android.

[Custom Drawing](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html)

[Custom Views](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html)

[Compound Views](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCustomViews/article.html)

**Option 2 :**
This option is to make user feel like screen is behaving same as requirement.

Take 6 different background images with center dynamic circle at center in it. Change background as per value selected. And place menu images using `RelativeLayout`. If you see menu images can be easily placed over the background using Relative layout, As two are `parent_left`, two are `parent_right`, one is `parent_top` and `center`, one is `parent_bottom` and `center`.

This is easiest option to implement, May give less accuracy but you can always tell designer to slightly adjust center, as per your layout. for such kind of UI both developer and designer must adjust upon few things.

**Option 3 :**
Use open source Widget and customize them as per need. But be careful about licence and/or paid versions and all. Read terms and conditions properly.

Many are available on google, I feel these are the best

[Circle Menu Widget](https://github.com/szugyi/Android-CircleMenu)

[Radial Menu Widget](https://github.com/strider2023/Radial-Menu-Widget-Android)

[Rotate Menu Widget](https://github.com/Bossyao168/RotateMenu)